# Java component not updating most of the time

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, java

I think I may have found a platform issue with openjdk-1.8.0_45 under ubuntu 15.04. The following program compiles and runs:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getSource());
        timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The time visually updates about twice per second until any kind of input happens to it - the mouse moves over it, it gets dragged, etc. Then it will get updated at the proper rate, or at least much faster. Does this happen on your system? Can anyone provide an explanation or theory for this behavior? If I put prints each time `timeLabel`'s `setText()` is called, I can see that it's being called approximately 20 times per second, but despite this the actual on-screen window is only being updated twice per second until other input events happen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using AWT instead of Swing? I would use a JFrame
2. Why are you doing custom painting? Just use a JLabel and add the JLabel to the JFrame and then you use the `setText(...)` method. Don't reinvent the wheel.
3. Why are you using Thread.sleep(). Use a Timer. A Timer is used to schedule an event. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Here is a complete example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getSource());
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to say "you are programming wrong, here's how you should do it", not actually answer the question. I understand that I am a novice programmer who doesn't understand the full Java API, but telling me "just do this" isn't very helpful.

Comment: Further, it doesn't solve the problem at all. I can set timer to a 50ms delay and it will still only actually update the value shown twice a second, until I move the mouse over it. (meant to be an edit, but past 5 mins)

Comment: @Reepca, `but telling me "just do this" isn't very helpful.` - I told you what not to do and suggest a better way to solve the problem. I don't know how I can be any more helpful.  `This answer seems to say "you are programming wrong, here's how you should do it",` - correct, you should spend time learning how to do things correctly. `it doesn't solve the problem at all.` - of course it does. Just change the text in the label to display the milliseconds. The point of the code was to get you started. You can change the Timer interval and the text displayed.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I compiled the example, changed the text in the label to display the milliseconds, changed the timer to a 50ms interval and the problem stayed the same as with my code. Your answer certainly does *not* solve the problem - that regardless of how frequently I attempt to cause the text to update, it will visually only update twice a second until I move the mouse over it.

Comment: @Reepca, I wouldn't waste my time telling you it works if it didn't work. It works fine for me using `JDK8 on Windows 7`. I have also used this code on JDK4 and WIndows XP. Maybe this is a version/platform issue. If you think the code doesn't work, they post the code you are now testing. State your version/platform. Stating something doesn't work is not helpful. Then maybe other people using your version will test to code as well to see if they have problems. The original code you posted will not help since it is not compilable or executable.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 15.04 and openjdk 1.8.0_45. Since the issue appears with code that you say works on your platform, I can only assume it's a platform issue. I tested using your code but changing all calls to `timeLabel.setText()` to set it to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and changing the interval `timer` was initialized with to 50. I will update the question to specifically use your code as the example to test with (with the changes I said I made). I apologize if I've been rude, I didn't expect the problem to not appear for others.