# JTextField gui help for number factoring calculator in java

Tags: java, jtextfield

Hi I am making a gui based number factoring calculator where you put in a number in a JtextField and you press a button to start the factoring. The factors will come out (in another JTextField) in two's one at a time with 5 second delay in between using a while loop... the only problem is that I cant seem to figure out how to have the 5 second delay in between factors.

Here is my code:

`

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;



class CloseListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class MyWin extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JTextField name, number, OutputName, OutputNumber;
    JButton CreateName, CreateNumber, clear, ok;
    MyWin(String title){

        super(title);


        this.setSize(750,625);
        this.init();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    void init() {
        JLabel lname = new JLabel("What is your name?:");
        name = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lnumber = new JLabel("What number do you want to to factor?");
        number = new JTextField(10);
        OutputName = new JTextField(50);
        OutputNumber = new JTextField(50);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(lname);
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(lnumber);`enter code here`
        panel.add(number);
        panel.add(OutputName);
        panel.add(OutputNumber);

        name.setBounds(375,0,100,25);
        lname.setBounds(250,0,150,25);
        number.setBounds(425,30,100,25);
        lnumber.setBounds(175,30,225,25);
        OutputName.setBounds(75,115,300,25);
        OutputNumber.setBounds(375,115,300,25);

        CreateName = new JButton("Create Name");
        CreateNumber = new JButton("Factor number");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        ok = new JButton("Close App");
        panel.add(CreateName);
        panel.add(CreateNumber);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(ok);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        CreateName.setBounds(150,60,150,25);
        clear.setBounds(300,60,150,25);
        ok.setBounds(450,60,150,25);
        CreateNumber.setBounds(295,85,160,25);


        CreateName.addActionListener(this);
        CreateNumber.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        ok.addActionListener(new CloseListener());
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        this.add(panel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == CreateName){
            String myname = "";
            myname = name.getText();
            OutputName.setText("Hi " + myname + "!");


        }
        else if(event.getSource() == CreateNumber){
            int mynumber = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());

            int x = 1;
            if(mynumber == 1){
                OutputNumber.setText("1 is only divisible by itself");
            }
            else if(mynumber > 0){
                while(mynumber >= x){
                    int y = mynumber / x;
                    if(mynumber % x == 0){
                        if(mynumber == x * y){
                            OutputNumber.setText(y + " and " + x);
                        }
                        x = x + 1;
                    }
                    else if(mynumber != y * mynumber){
                        x = x + 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        x = x + 1;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear){
            OutputName.setText("");
            OutputNumber.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

1. Don't use null layouts. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.
2. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct but some are not. Be consistent!!!

> the only problem is that I cant seem to figure out how to have the 5 second delay in between factors.

I would calculate all the factors and place them in a List. Then you can use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the display of the factors. When the Timer fires you remove a factor from the List and display it. When the List empty you stop the Timer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and examples.

You can also check out this simple [Timer example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763759/131872).

> The factors will come out (in another JTextField)

Maybe you could use a JTextArea and just add a new line to the text area to display the factor.